# Adjust view height to remove extra spaces in a constraint layout

Tags: android, xml, view, android-constraintlayout

Here, is how my screen looks like
[Login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES9Dj.jpg)

I want to remove extra spaces between the submit button and the bottom of the screen.
I researched about this issue in SO. But exactly no one answers it as far I have looked.
Can you suggest some ways to do so?
I have attached the XML layout below for reference.

Login layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.50"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopLogin"
            android:background="@drawable/round_cornered_top_white_bg_drawable"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:autofillHints="name"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_form"  />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:autofillHints="password"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etUsername"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/imgTogglePassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
            android:button="@drawable/btn_toggle_password"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/etPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/etPassword"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/etPassword" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/etPassword"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view_form"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginTopLogin"
            android:background="@drawable/round_cornered_top_white_bg_drawable"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="0.50" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:autofillHints="name"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view_form" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:autofillHints="password"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/view_form"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etUsername" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/imgTogglePassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-5dp"
            android:button="@drawable/btn_toggle_password"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/etPassword"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/etPassword"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/etPassword" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: It just aligns the submit at the bottom and spaces increase in between the password edit text and submit button. @Yura